# How do I prevent overlapping text in the Slideshow for WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, slideshow

I have vertically-overlapping text in the Slideshow for a website using WordPress. It only appears to occur on mobile devices, so I will need to apply my changes in CSS using @media query. The direct container outside of it is a div, which appears to not have a user defined name. I would normally just increase the height of the div class surrounding the area to see if that's the problem, but I can't seem to do that, and I can't seem to make the text smaller either. The text is implemented in the Slideshow section of WordPress in the Content Block as

`<h1 class="quote">Accelerate Your Career</h1>` etc..

Again this only happens on mobile devices when they are in portrait mode as far as I can tell. The website is http://avantirecruiters.com/

How can I prevent the overlapping text?
[image]

Comment: Set up a fiddle or add a screenshot that demonstrates the overlapping issue

Comment: Ok, I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the line-height **13px**. How about changing the line-height to **35px** or something similar?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 388px) and (min-width: 359px)
.caption-type2 > div h1.quote {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: -193px auto 5px auto!important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was having trouble with the reference to the element, but your parameter values worked as well. I discovered a way to test more than one device and it appeared to be screens with a resolution up to 400px so I tweaked your media query a bit.